# Git with Bash : exporting a subdirectory without getting the parent folder

Tags: git, bash, release, git-checkout

I have a little personal website.

To learn new things, I'm using git for my website and I would like to create a bash script which will do these steps :

1. Identify the last tag version
2. Checkout this version to a release specific folder (so my current work is not erased)
3. Minify the css file
4. Upload it on my ftp

This is complete overkill for a website with only an `index.html` and a `style.css` but this is just for the sake of learning something new. :)

I'm currently at step two, this work pretty well but I would like to make it a little better.

First, let met explain the tree view, it look like this :

```
/  
- scripts  
-- livraison  
- site  
-- index.html  
-- style.css
```

I got two sub folders in my parent folder, *scripts* and *site*. *scripts* doesn't contain any js scripts, all the source code of my website is in *site*. In fact, *scripts* does contain my bash script *livraison* that will do the release.

So I need to only checkout the `site` folder and place it into a release sub folder that I will name `site_livraison`

After a little research, I come up with this MWE:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Getting last tag version
dernierTag=$(git describe --tags `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1`)
echo 'Dernière version identifiée :' $dernierTag'.'
echo

# Emptying / Creating my release folder
echo 'Réinitialisation du répertoire "site_livraison".'
rm -Rf ../site_livraison
mkdir ../site_livraison
echo 'Réinitialisation du répertoire "site_livraison" terminée.'
echo

# Website source code checkout
echo 'Récupération de la version' $dernierTag' dans le répertoire "site_livraison".'
git --work-tree=../site_livraison checkout -f $dernierTag -- site

# Doing another checkout for going back to the master branch (if not I stay on my previous tag version and it mess up the git status command when I go back to developement)
git checkout -f master

echo 'Récupération de la version' $dernierTag' dans le répertoire "site_livraison" terminée.'
echo
```

My problem is after the execution of my script I get this tree view :

```
/  
- scripts  
-- livraison  
- site  
-- index.html  
-- style.css  
- site_livraison  
-- site  
--- index.html  
--- style.css
```

I would like to have this instead :

```
/  
- scripts  
-- livraison  
- site  
-- index.html  
-- style.css  
- site_livraison  
-- index.html  
-- style.css
```

Is there any way to do this in the `git` command while doing the check out or do I need to take all the files and make them "go up" in my treeview, then deleting the *--site* folder ?

Comment: First of all: since version 2.5 git [has a tool](https://github.com/blog/2042-git-2-5-including-multiple-worktrees-and-triangular-workflows) to create an additional worktree. In earlier versions a predecessor of this tool, [git-new-workdir](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/workdir/git-new-workdir) was available as a contrib. You don't need to mess your working repo with release code

Comment: Then: `git checkout`, well, simply checks out your source tree of a given state. So if you need to move things around, you need to change to source tree in the commit, or, well, apply those changes after checkout. There's no magical tool in `git` itself that would rewrite your source tree instantly, you only can create an additional script that would do it for you.

Comment: My OS is Debian, the current Git version in Synaptic that I have is 2.1.4. I can't use the git worktree and have to go for git-new-workdir.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some solutions would be:

1. Split project into multiple repos.  Keep your `scripts` and `site` in their own repos and then you can checkout each independently.  There wouldn't be the additional level of directories inside the repos to work around.
2. Another variation on #1 would be to use 3 repos.  1 repo each for `scripts` and `site` and then an encompassing `git` repo that treats the first two as [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).
3. Extract your working `site_livraison` outside of this same tree and then `mv` just the `site` subdir from that outside tree into where you want it.  This tree would no longer be a `git` repo, but if it is just for temporary purposes that could be harmless.

Comment: Hi, I don't get my *scripts* repository because of the command `git --work-tree=../site_livraison checkout -f $dernierTag -- site`. The `--site` indicate that I only want to checkout the *site* repository.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I succeed to do it. :)